# What happens if you don't use "this" within a class?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class foo{
public:
       int someNum;
       void calculation(int someNum);

};
```

Definition:

```
void foo::calculation(int someNum){
      someNum = someNum;
}
```

Now in the line `someNum = someNum` , which someNum is being referred to ?
If I do:

```
this->someNum = someNum
```

Then what is the second someNum ?

What is good naming style to avoid this problem ? For example, in objective-c, one prefixes "_" before a member variable name. (e.g.: _someNum);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inside a member function the parameter name hides identical class member names, so in

```
void foo::calculation(int someNum){
      someNum = someNum;
}
```

both `someNum`s are referring to the parameter. It's a self-assignment that doesn't change `this->someNum`.

In `this->someNum = someNum;`, the second `someNum` refers to the function parameter. So this assigns the value of the function parameter `someNum` to the class member `someNum`.

Common naming conventions include a `m` or `m_` prefix or a postfix `_` to class members. A prefix underscore can be problematic because C++ reserves names beginning with an underscore followed by a capital letter.

---

Note that member initializer lists in constructors is a special case:

```
foo(int someNum) : someNum(someNum) { someNum = someNum; }
                   ^        ^          ^         ^
                   |        |          |         |
                   |        ----------------------
                   |        These three all refer to the parameter 'someNum',
                   |        and not the class member.
                   |
     The language requires this name to be referring
     to a class member (or a base class) and so the  
     parameter called 'someNum' is not considered.
```

Comment: It is worth noting that this rule does not apply to a constructor's member initializer list. `foo(int someNum) : someNum(someNum) {}` does the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

The variable declared in the innermost scope shadows the variables in the outer scopes. So, `someNum = someNum'` in `foo::calculation` has no effect on the member variable `someNum`. Instead, someNum refers to the argument passed in. To help alleviate this, naming standards suggest prefixing your member variables with a consistent identifier - "m_", for example.